# Is there an AWS API to list all possible IAM actions, permissions for specific services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I'm looking for an API containing information similar to the 'Actions, Resources & Condition Keys' portion of the Policy Reference for IAM:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html

Comment: Did you end up finding any resources for this?

Comment: I did not. let me know if you find anything.